# Who knows how can I correctly draw the arrows?

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-trees

I am drawing the scheme and use the Tikz library as following:

```
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}
```

So, my code which has to draw the arrow between nodes is following:

```
\tikzstyle{Node1} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10]
\node (Node1) [Node1, xshift=-4cm] {Node1};
\draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
```

And it gives the error in line of arrow (`\draw...`)

Which library or command should I use to draw arrows?

Comment: Any news? You got two answer, Does no one is worth to be upvoted or on of them even accepted?

Answer (score 2):

You information is as unclear as they can get, but I am willing to take wild guesses.

You did not have defined what arrow in the optional arguments in the `\draw` does also you do not have a `start` node nor an `in1` node.

Once you define all this things, the code works.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\tikzset{
    arrow/.style = {-stealth},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        
        \tikzstyle{Node1} = [rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black, fill=blue!10]
        \node (Node1) [Node1, xshift=-4cm] {Node1};
        
        \node (start) [Node1, xshift=-9cm] {1};
        
        \node (in1) [Node1, xshift=-4cm] {2};
        
        
        \draw [arrow] (start) -- (in1);
        
        \end{tikzpicture}
        
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, @Roland! I didn't type this \tikzset{
    arrow/.style = {-stealth},
}

Comment: You do not have to you could alternatively just write `-stealth` in the optional arguments of `\draw` like `\draw [-stealth]` but writing arrow in it wihtout defining it makes (of course) an error.

Comment: thanks a lot, will learn it :)

Comment: @Programmer1988 If my answer solved your problem it would be nice to accept, so that it is also marked as accepted as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Best

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to TeX.SE!

- Always provide complete small document, beginning with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}` which we can copy and compile in our computers as it is and  which reproduce your problem.
- Your code fragments are far from that:

  - Your picture had to be in `tikzpicture` environment
  - You need to define all elements of image! In your case are not defined `start`, `in1` and `arrow`
- possible example of your image can be:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
Node1/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
                align=center, draw=black, fill=blue!10},
arrow/.style = {-Straight Barb}
        }
        
\node (Node1) [Node1, xshift=-4cm] {Node1};
\coordinate (start) at (0,0);
\coordinate (in1)   at (3,0);
\draw[arrow] (start) -- (in1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Above code use correct syntax for defining style. Use of `tikzstyle` is deprecated, also better than use library `arrow` is to use `arrows.meta` In your case not need library `shapes.geometric`, rectangle is availabel in `tikz` document class.

[image]

I doubt that you looking for this, but your question is unclear what you after. Maybe you looking for the following:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{
Node1/.style = {rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm,
                align=center, draw=black, fill=blue!10},
arrow/.style = {-Straight Barb}
        }
        
\coordinate (start) at (0,0);
\coordinate (in1)   at (3,0);
\draw[arrow] (start) -- (in1) node[Node1, right] {Node1};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which gives

[image]

Please, read some introductory text about `tikz` package like [wiki LaTeX/PGF/TikZ](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/PGF/TikZ)or the first tutorial in package documentation.